# How to reuse symbols from a hash in another method in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, metaprogramming

I have the following method that defines a hash with a number of keys (there are a lot, I just cut it down for this example).

```
def data
  @data ||= {
    name: "Some Name",
    email: "my@email.com"
  }
end
```

Now, each of those keys I want to use in another method within the same class like so:

```
[:name, :email].each { |key| define_method("get_#{key}") { data[key] } }
```

While this works as it should, it doesn't seem to be a very good idea to hardcode the keys - I'd would much rather make them dynamic and have them reused from the hash I created within the first method. Since I am calling upon an Instance of this Class from another Class I get the following error when using the obvious approach:

```
data.keys.each { |key| define_method("get_#{key}") { data[key] } }

# => undefined local variable or method `data' for #<Class:0x0000000dc55938>
```

Any ideas how this could be solved?

Comment: If you want to use in same class then what is the problem, just call that method and use the keys. Do you want to use the keys in another class ?

Comment: @pramod I updated the question to clarify the problem.

Comment: It seems that you are not calling upon instance of this class from another class. Because if you want to call data method you must call it from the class instance that where you defined. for example, if data method present in class A then you must call it from instance of A if you don't have  any inheritance mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

As both methods are in same class why not use `data` instead of `@data`

```
2.1.2 :001 > def data
2.1.2 :002?>     @data ||= {
2.1.2 :003 >           name: "Some Name",
2.1.2 :004 >           email: "my@email.com"
2.1.2 :005?>       }
2.1.2 :006?>   end
 => :data 
2.1.2 :007 > data.keys.each { |key| define_method("get_#{key}") { data[key] } }
 => [:name, :email] 
2.1.2 :008 > get_name
 => "Some Name" 
2.1.2 :009 >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define method like `data_keys`. Use this method outside of your class and get keys.

```
class YourClass
  def self.data
    ...
  end

  def self.data_keys
    @data_keys ||= data.keys
  end
end

YourClass.data_keys.each { |key| define_method("get_#{key}") { YourClass.data[key] } }
```

Comment: Can you give an example for this?

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'data_keys' for YourClass:Class`... use `def self.data_keys`???

Comment: doesn't matter, where you define your `definge_method`, you can get access to data anywhere. YourClass only store your data.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:--

```
  def  data(*args)
      options = args.extract_options!
      options ||= {
        name: "Some Name",
        email: "my@email.com"
      }
   ##save it to instance variable for further use
    @data=options
    ##either pass to another method
    other_method(options)
    ##or call any other method to call private methods as well using send
    new_obj =OtherObject.new
    new_obj.send(:method_name,options)

    end
```

**same solution ,,using class variable**

```
def data
  @@data ||= {
    name: "Some Name",
    email: "my@email.com"
  }
end

in this way..you can even access data in model

def get_data
  ##  @@data is available
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding your requirements correctly, you want to have methods on each instance of the class that map (with a get/set prefix) to the keys in the data hash?

Although I despise magical logic in classes, could you not just define `#method_missing` and handle getting the value from the data hash based on that?

```
def method_missing method_symbol, *args, &block
    if method_symbol.to_s.match(/^get_(.+)$/) && data.keys.include?($1.to_sym)
        # Using the matching key in the data hash
        data[$1.to_sym]
    else
        # Cannot detect method for current class, bubble method_missing to super class
        super
    end
end
```

It should also be noted that when overrideing method missing, you should always override `#respond_to?` as well